# How to add JavaScript in JEditorPane of java?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I am working on a project and I am developing web browser and I want to run JavaScript. Google page open but scripts are not run. So how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write your own JavaScript engine as a part of the web browser you're developing, you could try using the `ScriptEngineManager` from the `javax.script` package.

See [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) for examples on how this works.